# Forecast infected incidence of a disease

Tags: statistics, discrete-mathematics, time-series

I want to forecast infected incidence of a disease using suitable forecasting methods. I already used Weighted Markov Chain and ARIMA time series. What are the other ways to make predictions?

Thank You